# push sql server table change notifications to iOS device

Tags: ios, sql-server, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I would need your help in below assignment. I have done some initial research but the team lead is suggesting to look for alternative options as external libraries would not be good fit from security perspective.

Requirement is whenever there is change in sql server table (DML operations) notifications should be send out to an API or if directly to iOS app using Amazon Web Services(AWS).

I checked and found that this can be achieved using SignalR but as this is third party package we are little bit concerned. Could you please suggest other alternatives to achieve the same thing? Is it possible to push sql server notifications to iOS app directly using AWS, if yes how we can do it? I have not done this before, open for suggestions.

Regards,
lbad

Answer (score 0):

The "third party" developing SignalR is primarily Microsoft and source code is open: https://github.com/signalr/signalr. You can audit the code if you want.

If you wish to avoid third party libraries, you can write a trigger in your database that will invoke .NET code on nay update and call external API. Here is an example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/938d9dz2(v=vs.80).aspx

Then again, .NET and SQL Server are developed by Microsoft, the very same company that created SignalR.

Comment: Thanks Sergey Kovalev for your valuable comments. I have gone through the documentation available at msdn link you suggested but I couldn't find the code calling API? Could you please share the code which calls API when trigger is fired?